Degree of a smooth map is nonzero implies that it is surjective
I would like to prove that if $f: M\to N$ is a smooth map between oriented manifolds with $M$ compact, then $\text{deg}f\neq0$ implies that $f$ is surjective.
Here is my attempt :
Let $y\in N\setminus f(M)$. By density of the regular values of $f$ in $N$ there exists a sequence $(y_n)_n$ of regular values that converges to $y$. We can associated a sequence $x_n$ to $y_n$ such that $f(x_n)=y_n$, up to a subsequence (by compactness) using the continuity of $f$ we have $f(x)=y$ for some $x\in M$.
I think this is false because I do not see where I am using the fact that $\text{deg}f\neq 0$ however I cannot see the formal error.
If you have some help to provide I will appreciate.
Thank you a lot

You are applying Sard's theorem incorrectly.

@MikhailKatz Thank you for your comment ! Oh my bad, but I do not see why, since the set of regular values of $f$ being dense in $N$ I can approximate any point of $N$ by a sequence of regular values no ?

If you are going to count the points in $N\setminus f(M)$ as regular values, then you cannot automatically deduce from $y_n$ being regular, that there is $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)=y_n$. You could, nevertheless, compare the (local) degree. At $N\setminus f(M)$ the degree is zero. You would be using that degree is locally constant.

@ameg Thank you a lot. If I understand well, at some point I may encounter a $y_n$ no more in $f(M)$ and so the $f(x_n)=y_n$ could not hold. I will see what can I do given your hint, thank you !

I don't understand why you're making this so difficult. If there is any point $y\in N$ not in the image, then $y$ is automatically a regular value and therefore $\deg(f)=0$.

@TedShifrin You are right !  I realized after that by definition it was clear
